# Oh My Posh: getting whether or not in a Git repo in other segments

Tags: git, oh-my-posh

So I was creating my own Oh-My-Posh profile when I ran into a problem.

The profile I want to make is:

When into a repo:

```
{{ .Git.UserName }}@{{ .Git.Branch }}:{{ .Git.Repo.Name }}{{ .FurtherPath }}$
```

and when not into a repo:

```
{{ .System.UserName }}@{{ .System.Hostname }}:{{ .System.Path }}$
```

so for example Let's say that there exists a git repo at the path: `~\directory0\directory1\repo\` and that there exists the directory `~\directory0\directory1\repo\source\code`.

Then the prompt should look like this when in for example directory `directory1`:

```
user@host:~\directory0\directory1$
```

but when I go into the `code` directory inside of the `repo` it should look like this:

```
git_user@git_branch:git_repo_name\source\code$
```

I managed to fetch of UserName, HostName, and Path. That was easy, however the problem is that I can't tell wether or not I'm in a git repo. I could use the `"type" : "Git"`, however if you are not in a repo then this would result in that that segment not being rendered.

So my question is:

1. is there a way such that in another segment I can use something like `{{ if .Git }}...{{ end }}`? Then I could use something like `{{ if .Git }}{{ .Git.UserName }}{{ else }}{{ .UserName }}{{ end }}`.
2. Is there a way such that I can get the path starting within the repo starting directory?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question does not appear to be about programming or software development. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) from the help center. General questions about interactive shell use and configuration (like prompt customization) can be asked on [Linux & Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way such that in another segment I can use something like
> {{ if .Git }}...{{ end }}? Then I could use something like {{ if .Git
> }}{{ .Git.UserName }}{{ else }}{{ .UserName }}{{ end }}.

You can accomplish what you want in question 1 by taking advantage [Cross Segment Template Properties](https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/configuration/templates#cross-segment-template-properties).

This will allow you to reference segment data available in the Git segment.  In your case, it would be the [Git User information](https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/segments/git#user).  **NOTE:**  In order to have the Git user information available, you will have to make sure to [enable the fetch_user property](https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/segments/git#fetching-information).

Here's a sample template (*yaml format*) that does what you're requesting in part 1:

```
$schema: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JanDeDobbeleer/oh-my-posh/main/themes/schema.json
version: 2
blocks:
  
  - newline: true
    alignment: left
    segments:
      - type: path
        style: plain
        template: "{{ if .Segments.Git.User.Name }}{{ .Segments.Git.User.Name }}@{{ .Segments.Git.User.Email }}:{{ .Segments.Git.RepoName }} {{else}} {{ .UserName }}@{{ .HostName }}:{{ .Path }} {{ end }}"
        properties:
          style: folder

      - type: git
        style: plain
        template: " {{ .HEAD }}"
        properties:
          fetch_user: true
    type: prompt

  - newline: true
    alignment: left
    segments:
      - style: plain
        type: text
        template: "$"
    type: prompt
final_space: true
```

> Is there a way such that I can get the path starting within the repo
> starting directory?

This may be doable with [matchP Helper Function](https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/configuration/templates#custom) and/or/combo-of-both [mapped_locations property of the Path segment](https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/segments/path#mapped-locations).  However, I don't think this would be very straight forward; and I personally am not sure how to do it.

I do think that taking advantage of the Path Segment and its different [styles](https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/segments/path#style) could get you something that would be a good alternative; but that would depend on what you're wanting from changing the relative start directory, based on being in a repository or not.